# PHP - XML get childrens by name value

Tags: php, xml, xpath, multidimensional-array

i have this function that get values from XML and create an multidimensinal array.

```
function esummary_query($db, $id) { 
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
      'http'=>array(
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'
       )
    ));

    $xml = file_get_contents('http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=' . $db . '&id=' . $id, FALSE, $context);

    $xml_file = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $results2 = array();
      $c=0;
    foreach ( $xml_file->DocSum as $items ) {
        $results2[$c]['id'] = $items->Id;
        $authors = $xml_file->xpath("//Item[@Name='Author']");
        foreach ($authors as $author) {
            $results2[$c]['authors'][] = $author;
        }
          $c++;
    }
    return $results2;
}
```

But this get all items with name="Author" each time that read a DocSum. I know that occurs because i am selecting all items with name="authors" wherever they are, but if i put $xml_file->xpath("/Item[@Name='Author']") or $items->xpath("/Item[@Name='Author']") it not working.

This is the [XML](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=24214952,24214944,24214591).

How can i do it?

Thanks!

Comment: "//Item[@Name='Author'] => Anywhere in the document find ...
"/Item[@Name='Author']" => from the root element find children named "Item" element which have an attribute named 'Name' which has the value 'Author'.
"Item[@Name='Author']" => from my CURRENT node, find children....

Comment: As you already guessed your XPath statement has to be more selective. However, we cannot know which `Item` you want to select unless you give us at least a sketch of the XML that you are parsing. The URL you are using only works for known id's.

Comment: i have put a link to XML in the question

Answer (score 0):

`//DocSum/Id[text()="24214944"]/..//Item[@Name="Author"]` returns the list of authors of DocSum that has 24214944 as id. Expanding from that you can construct the xpath query dynamically:

```
$results2[$c]['id'] = $items->Id;
$authors = $xml_file->xpath('//DocSum/Id[text()="' . $items->Id . '"]/..//Item[@Name="Author"]');
foreach ($authors as $author) {
    $results2[$c]['authors'][] = $author;
}
```